# In the context of sexual performance, what's correct? 'On bed' or 'In bed'

Tags: prepositions

The context is clear - sexual performance. Which one is preferred and why?

> [I am | You are | He is | She is] so good on bed.
>   [I am | You are | He is | She is] so good in bed.

Answer (score 4):

"In bed". In fact any phrase referring to being in a bed is always "in bed", unless we are specifically referring to something **on top** of the bed.

Let's see:

> Under the covers, sheets, duvet or quilt, referring to sex, sleeping or otherwise, is always "**in bed**".

Imagine we're asking about a lost object, for example, here we should (likely) use "on the bed".

> Have you seen my jacket?
>
> Yeah, I think you left it on the bed.

There are times when we can refer to sleeping "on" rather than "in" bed. Specifically, this is when you don't get into bed "properly". Imagine you come home drunk, and don't quite make it **under** the covers, you may well say:

> Cor! I slept terribly. I spent the night on the bed, cos I couldn't work out how to get under the covers.